# Javascript split slice join string

Tags: javascript, string, join, split, slice

I am struggling a bit with this problem.

I have a string "Jan van Wyk". "Jan" is the firstname and "van Wyk" is the lastname.

```js
let enqBy = "Jan van Wyk";
var firstName = enqBy.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
var lastName = enqBy.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
console.log(firstName);
console.log(lastName);
```

Using this code the result is `firstname = "Jan van"` and `lastname = "Wyk"` which is not what I want.

If I have a string like "Elvis Presly" the code works perfectly `firstname = "Elvis"` and `lastname = "Presley"`.

Please guide me.

Comment: Will the first name always be the first word, and the remaining words the last name ?

Comment: `s.replace(' ','_').split('_')` ??

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say, if I execute your code firstname is `Jan van` and lastname is `Wyck`

Comment: Your code doesn't behave how you've explained it does (I've made you a code snippet), although it still doesn't produce your expected output

Comment: Also, it's bad to categorize names based on the space. The firstname, lastname logic is different for different locations and cultures.

Comment: Parsing real names is a very complicated task. With any amount of code, you can only hope to parse a tiny subset of what's possible in the real world. Before you go any further, take some time and define which name variations you're going to accept and which not (for example, how about `Jan Wellem van Wyk`? or `Karl-Theodor Maria von und zu Wick` etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you state in your question:  `"Jan" is the firstname and "van Wyk" is the lastname.`

Then you want to pick the first item for firstname and the rest for lastname, this code would do:

```
const [firstname, ...rest] = enqBy.split(' ')
const lastname = rest.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems to work on my side, Hope I got your to question well but just adjusted the first name to the first string after the split and joined the last two with a space.

```js
const enqBy = "Jan van Wyk"

var firstName = enqBy.split(' ')[0]; 
var lastName = enqBy.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');

console.log(firstName)
console.log(lastName)

// Output
// "Jan"
// "van Wyk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below. This also works for names like "Elvis Presly" that have one single word for last name .

```js
    var enqBy = "Jan van Wyk";
    var firstName = enqBy.split(" ").slice(0, 1).join(" ");
    var lastName = enqBy.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first name of sentence, get the split using the space and then to get lastname get the length of sentence and slice.

```js
let abc = "Praveen Ash Surya"
var fname = abc.split(' ', 1).join(' ');
var lname = abc.split(' ', abc.length).slice(1).join(' ');
console.log(fname);
console.log(lname);
```

Split can be used with separator and limit

**`lastname.split(seperator, ?limit)`**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```js
const fullName = "Jan van Wyk"
const regex = /^(\w+\s)(.*)$/g
const matches = regex.exec(fullName)
matches.shift() // remove first value which is the fullName
const [firstName, lastName] = matches

console.log(firstName.trim()) // Jan
console.log(lastName.trim()) // van Wyk
```

The first group this regex matches is the name (some letters + space) second group is the rest of the fullName.